# compare two strings and remove common character from second and concatenate uncommon?

Tags: java, string, duplicates

This is code of compare two strings and remove common character from second 
and concatenate uncommon. But output is not proper.

```
import java.util.*;

class str1 { 
    //create class


    public static void main(String[] args) { 
   //main function

        String str = "hello My name is"; 
    //string one
        String str2 = "viral";  
    //string two


        char s1[] = str.tocharArray();// string convert into character 
        char s2[] = str2.tocharArray();  // string convert into character

        for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
                if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
                    s2[j] = '\0';
                    s2[j] = s2[j + 1];

                }

            }
        }

        String s1cpy = s1.toString();
        String s2cpy = s2.toString();

        String s3 = s1cpy + s2cpy;

        System.out.println("the string after removing common character  and concatenation is " + s3);

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output you expect after your code execution?

Comment: common characters remove from second  string and concatenate with first . it is the required output

Comment: what i meant is if string S is hello and String two is  Helloworld, what is output you expect?

Comment: it should be like" world "  hello is removed

Comment: if the String S is hello and String two is HelloworldHelloWorld, then your output should be worldWorld right?

Comment: To be double sure, since you mentioned in question as Character and not string. Then does that mean if s1 is hello world and s2 is hcdl then result shall be "eo wor" removing char h, d and l?

Comment: i just convert both strings to chararray so that common between them should be remove

Comment: for ex: s1="abcd" and s2="aac" then output what i want is "bd "

Comment: how could i achieve this

Comment: You have mentioned that you wanted to remove common character from the second string, then for your example  for ex: s1="abcd" and s2="aac" how can you get bd? as its a part of first String. 

Moreover going back to S hello and String Two Helloworld, the result   should be wrd right?

Comment: then what would be the right logic for it .

Comment: yes !! but in case of s1="hello" and s2="helloworld" and s1 loop will end after comparing last character of s1 because of s1.length is less then other string it would not compare further i think

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can use replace method, it's so much easier.

Secondly, array.toString() will not work, you need to use String.copyValueOf(char[]).

```
        //char s1[] = str.toCharArray();// string convert into character

        //char s2[] = str2.toCharArray();  // string convert into character

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
           str2 = str2.replace(str.charAt(i),'\0');
        }


        String s3 = str + str2;
```

Maybe not the perfect solution, but works properly like you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Check your logic, it seem wrong to me. See my code comments:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s1[i] == s2[j]) {
                s2[j] = '\0'; // Here you assign \0 to s2[j]
                s2[j] = s2[j + 1]; // And here you assign s2[j+1] to s2[j], so you overwrite the \0 you just set previously.

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: the purpose of writing s2[j]=s2[j+1] if s1="abcc" and if found common character then we assign null to that index and increment by  1 so that next character take its position instead of omitting next char value

Answer (score 0):

You could change your loop as follows (to add in a random character - perhaps not ideal but gives you the output I think you want):

```
String str = "hello My name is";
        String str2 = "viral";

        for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        for (char d : str2.toCharArray()) {
            if (c == d) {
                str2 = str2.replace(d, ';');
            }
        }
    }
    str2 = str2.replaceAll(";", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    //main function

    String str = "hello My name is"; 
    //string one
    String str2 = "viral";  
    //string two

    String commonChars = "";

    //creating a string of all common chars
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < str2.length(); j++) {
            if (str.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(j)) {

                commonChars += str.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }


    //replace common chars in str and str2 with a blank 
    for(int i = 0; i < commonChars.length(); i ++)
    {
        String charToRemove = commonChars.charAt(i)+"";//change char to string
        str = str.replace(charToRemove, "");
        str2 = str2.replace(charToRemove, "");

    }

    String s3= str+str2;

    System.out.println("the string after removing common character  and concatenation is " + s3);

}
```

Comment: ohhh!! thank you but can you explain a little about your logic

Comment: first, instead of transferring the strings to two arrays, I simply run through the strings. Then I collected all the common chars from str and str2 to a string - commonChars. Then, on the second for loop, I ran through commonChars, and used the String.replace() function to replace all common chars from both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Check my solution ......

```
import java.util.*;

public class RCC
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String s1 = "", s2 = "";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n Enter the String 1 : ");
        s1 =scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\n Enter the String 2 : ");
        s2 =scan.nextLine();

        String a = s1;
        String b = s2;
        char temp = s1.charAt(0);
        String search = "";
        String replace = "";

        for(int i= 0; i < s1.length(); i++)
        {
            temp = s1.charAt(i);
            search = Character.toString(temp);

            for(int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++)
            {
                if(temp == s2.charAt(j))
                {
                    a = a.replace(search, replace);
                    b = b.replace(search, replace);
                }
            }       
        }

        System.out.println("\n Common Characters Removed String 1 : " + a);
        System.out.println("\n Common Characters Removed String 2 : " + b);

    }
}
```